# HHVM and nginx not sending headers immediately

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I have a PHP download script that dynamically bundles files into zips. So the user feels like something is happening immediately, we send a header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.zip"); as soon as possible and then start trickling out the files. In our traditional Apache/PHP setup, that works great but we're trying to get our codebase to run on an nginx/HHVM server and it doesn't send the headers the same way.

Rather, nginx/HHVM waits to send the headers until its done a lot of the processing (I'm not sure how much) and, from HHVM's perspective, sent out several files. This means the user ends up waiting a long time before getting a Save As dialog and it's creating a bad experience.

In my nginx site config, I set

```
fastcgi_buffering off;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
proxy_buffering off;
```

I also tried adding flush(); and header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); in PHP but nothing seems to help.

Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: In case it's relevant, I'm using HHVM 3.6.0 and nginx 1.6.2